# Missing files when Windows 7 returns from hibernate w/ dual boot

Tags: windows, ubuntu, filesystems, hibernate, samba

I have a dual-boot setup with Ubuntu (lucid) and Windows 7. I have the Windows file system shared on Ubuntu through Samba.

Occasionally, I am working on Windows and my machine will go into hibernate (i.e. when the battery level is critical). By default, my GRUB settings boot me into Ubuntu. So when I get back to my PC, sometimes I just hop into Ubuntu instead of going back to Windows. However, if I write any files to the Windows file system during that Ubuntu session, the next time I do go back to Windows (which resumes from hibernate), those files are missing.

Obviously, the state of the actual file system and the hibernate snapshot become out of sync, and Windows chooses the hibernate snapshot, overriding any changes I may have made thru Ubuntu. For now, I've disabled the hibernate option in the Windows power settings, but is there any utility I can use to get back some of those missing files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In principle, it should be possible. Try a file recovery software. Recuva should help. http://www.piriform.com/recuva

Comment: Thanks. It couldn't find the missing files (might be too late now), but it seems like a great recovery utility.

Comment: It was able to find the files I deleted from the new directory I had created in Linux that went missing, but not the files that I didn't delete. Deep scan also didn't find the files.

Answer (score 0):

Recuva is a good choice for recovery back then i used it allot but then i
discovered [r-studio](http://www.data-recovery-software.net/) it is AWESOME. it is available for windows/mac/linux it recovers
the following file systems

- FAT12/16/32/exFAT, NTFS, NTFS5 (windows)
- HFS/HFS+ macintosh
- Little and Big Endian variants of UFS1/UFS2 (FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, Solaris)
  Ext2/Ext3/Ext4 FS (linux)

It recovers from local and network disk even if the partitions are damaged formatted or deleted

Here are some more features posted on the website

**R-Studio utilities recover files:**

```
Deleted without Recycle Bin, or when Recycle Bin has been emptied;
Removed by virus attack or power failure;
After the partition with the files was reformatted, even for different file system;
When the partition structure on a hard disk was changed or damaged. In this case, R-Studio utilities can scan the hard disk trying to find previously existing partitions and recover files from found partitions.
From hard disk with bad sectors. R-Studio Data Recovery Software can first copy the entire disk or its part into an image file and then process the image file. This is especially useful when new bad sectors are constantly appearing on the hard disk and remaining information must be immediately saved.
```

i don't know how many times this app saved my/family/friends/others data, countless times, and it rarely fails :)