# Corrupted windows file system after upgrading ubuntu nautilus

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, ubuntu-16.04, filesystem-corruption, nautilus

Currently, I'm ended up with a separate and shared NTFS partition with possible of ~49GB data lose. the partition is shared between Windows10(1903) and Ubuntu 16.04.

It must have happened after upgrading nautilus to 3.18, and worth to mention `Window hibernate` and `Windows Fast StartUp` was **OFF**

Windows File Explorer shows the total used space as `337GB` while now the content's size is `288GB`! and some set of files/dirs are missing.

Are there any filesystem rebuild/recovery options here?

What's the solution?

Already tried:

- SFC

  - `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`
  - `sfc /scannow`
- CHKDSK

  - `chkdsk /f`

Already checked:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064482
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/105958
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/49000
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/49000
- [Everything on my NTFS partition disappeared](https://superuser.com/questions/745794)
- [Missing files when Windows 7 returns from hibernate w/ dual boot](https://superuser.com/questions/144720)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shut down Windows immediately.

The more you use Windows on that PC with that partition mounted, the more clusters will get overwritten, so your chance of total recovery is best if you shut down Windows immediately.

Next, reboot into Ubuntu, and dismount the shared partition.

Use [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) or a disk cloning app of your choice to make a duplicate copy of that volume.

The free Open Source apps [TestDisk and PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#Recover_deleted_files) can be installed on your Ubuntu OS.

Then, remount the shared partition, and search for what you can recover on that NTFS partition with TestDisk, then PhotoRec.

Comment: more bad news:( gnome disk show 7472 bad sectors on the device!: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vODf2.png

Comment: And, that's after CHKDSK /F .... It's Clonezilla time to try to protect what's on the drive, fer sure. All of the drive. Then replace the drive.